# Custom font for Android listview

Tags: android, listview, fonts

I have a custom font for my android activity.

**MainActivity.class**

```
    private void initControls() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    header = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvAccommodations);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lvAccommodations);
    text = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/heartbre.ttf");
    header.setTypeface(tf);
    text.setTypeface(tf);



    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.abra_hotel, R.layout.custom_list_text);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            header.setText(value);
```

**custom_list_text.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:text="@string/app_name"
android:paddingLeft="6dip" />
```

Android throws NullPointerException. Why is it so? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**LOGCAT:**

```
    03-08 19:48:03.859: E/AndroidRuntime(413): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-08 19:48:03.859: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.say.philippineexplorer.PlaceAccommodations.initControls(PlaceAccommodations.java:34)
    03-08 19:48:03.859: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.say.philippineexplorer.PlaceAccommodations.onCreate(PlaceAccommodations.java:22)
```

Comment: post the log exception

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes what is line 34 and 22?

Comment: this line: text.setTypeface(tf);

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes : post your full Activity  onCreate  method code

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes : u will need to override getView method to set custom font see this example and change your code as :http://pastebin.com/bcVSmPJG

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the custom adapter class and the constructor

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    CharSequence data[] = null;
    Typeface tf; 

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, CharSequence[] data, String FONT ) { 
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT);
}
```

Put the font you want to use in your assets folder and fill your listview like this:

```
listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_text, R.array.abra_hotel, "name_of_font.ttf");
```

Comment: It is not working for my adapter, here is the SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439707/typeface-not-taking-place-in-custom-arrayadapter?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: You created a property called `tf` and set a `Typeface` to it, but `tf` isn't assigned to anything.  How does this code set the font of the item renderer?

Comment: I put font sin "src/assets/fonts/myfont.ttf" and passed into the adapter "fonts/myfont.ttf" and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can't apply font directly to listview and you need to create custom adapter for listview and change it font for more details click below stack post it's already discussed.

[How to change color and font on ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361135/how-to-change-color-and-font-on-listview)