# How to disable click event for certain elements in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am using AutoCompleteTextView (ref : [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) )

I am able to get list of auto suggestion provided by this view.

Now I want to disable the second suggestion from this view.

Can you please tell me how to achieve it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom data adapter for your `AutoCompleteTextView` by extending `ArrayAdapter` and then **override** `isEnabled` method from that custom adapter to define which items are click-able or not.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.isEnabled(position);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I change the disable element text color ?

Comment: usually it automatically lightens the textcolor of disabled item. but if you want to override that behaviour, then simply override `getView` method within the same adapter and set a custom color to your disabled items

Comment: Well i override getView and able to change the background color but not able to change text color how can I achieve that ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361135/how-to-change-color-and-font-on-listview) should help you to understand how to change text color particularly