# android change listview font and color

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, fonts

I've found loads of different ways of accomplishing this but I'm not sure what's the best for my scenario.

This is my Java code for the listview:

```
ListView lv;
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favList);
```

This is the xml code for the list:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/favList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
    </ListView>
```

For a text view I would add:

```
final Typeface fontList = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "optima-extra-black.ttf");
lv.setTypeface(fontList);
```

But this doesn't work for listviews.
How do I change my font in this case?

Oke I'm almost there...
I need to access my assets but I can't from within my custom adapter.
I tried using `final AssetManager assets = this.getAssets();` but that won't get me any further..

How to tackle this?

```
    class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater lif;
    ImageView sideArrow;
    TextView tv;


    public Myadapter(Context ctx) {
        lif = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return favarets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = lif.inflate(R.layout.inflate, null);
        sideArrow = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewsidemark);

        tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textFav);
        tv.setText(favarets.get(position));
        final AssetManager assets = this.getAssets();
        final Typeface tvFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "OPTIMA.TTF");
        tv.setTypeface(tvFont);

        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        return vi;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out the solution :D

```
    public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter {

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets(); 

    LayoutInflater lif;
    ImageView sideArrow;
    TextView tv;


    public Myadapter(Context ctx) {
        lif = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return favarets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = lif.inflate(R.layout.inflate, null);
        sideArrow = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewsidemark);


        tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textFav);
        tv.setText(favarets.get(position));

        final Typeface tvFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "OPTIMA.TTF");
        tv.setTypeface(tvFont);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        return vi;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The list view itself isn't responsible for drawing the items, it uses an [adapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews) to create the list items. This adapter creates a view to display the list item when required.
To change the font used to display the list item, you have to change the adapter to return a view with the new font. This can be done in the [Adapter.getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method.
If you are currently using a standard Adapter implementation, you may need to subclass it (or completely replace it).

Comment: Oke Thanks I'll read through the documentation. I did understand that the listview isn't handling the appearance of the text inside it but how to tell the textviw indside the listview to change it's font could be done trough the adapter.getview method?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a `custom adapter`.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7361323/1932105) answer

and then have a `custom xml` too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="20px" android:paddingTop="10dip" android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

then set the custom adapter to your `listview`.

```
listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(YourActivity.this , R.layout.custom_list , mList);
mListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: I'm sorry  I just can't get my head around it isn't there a simpler approach to this?

Comment: this is simplest approach. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, instead of using the inbuild xml file in the SKD

```
`ArrayAdapter ad=new ArrayAdapter(GuestActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);`
```

Make your own xml layout file like this-

```
`<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/YourStyle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />`
```

and use that in the adapter.

Sample Image:

[image: Formatted List Item]

Answer (score 0):

**Just set it to the TextView which you are inflating
set the typeface in adapter or in the xml layout.**

Comment: How would I do this and do I really need 40+ lines of code to change a font as suggested by Ahmed Ekri?

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textview_in_listview_infliyater);
final Typeface fontList = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "optima-extra-black.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(fontList);

Answer (score 0):

create custom Text view layout
Step 1:
create new layout for example listview_custom
Step 2:
clear all code in listview_custom
Step 3:
Insert the following code

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
<!-- change background color -->    
android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
<--!change text color-->
    android:textColor="@color/black"
<--!insert font--> 
    android:fontFamily="@font/iransansweb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

And set listview Adapter very easy

```
ArrayAdapter ad=new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.listview_custom,list);
listview.setAdapter(ad)
```