# Why can't setTypeFace() be resolved?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change the font in my Android app with the code below. However, it keeps throwing `setTypeFace() cannot be resolved` at me and I don't know why.

```
navListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.nav_listView);

// Font path
String ralewayBold = "fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf";
String ralewayExtraBold = "fonts/Raleway-ExtraBold.ttf";
String ralewayExtraLight = "fonts/Raleway-ExtraLight.ttf";
String ralewayHeavy = "fonts/Raleway-Heavy.ttf";
String ralewayLight = "fonts/Raleway-Light.ttf";
String ralewayMedium = "fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf";
String ralewayRegular = "fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf";
String ralewaySemiBold = "fonts/Raleway-SemiBold.ttf";
String ralewayThin = "fonts/Raleway-Thin.ttf";

// Loading Font Face
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext()
            .getAssets(), ralewayLight);

// Applying font
navListView.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: you have to set this typeface at list item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTypeface` is a method of `TextView` and not of `ListView`.

If you want to set custom font style to text in `ListView` you have to do it in `getView` of your custom adapter

Comment: Excuse me if it's stupid, but how do I do what you just suggested?

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896887/android-change-listview-font-and-color)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you set typeface to `listview` directly.To set typeface to `listview` use **custom adapter** and settypeface in `getView` method in adapter.

To set typeface see these post

[Custom font for Android listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293437/custom-font-for-android-listview)

[android change listview font and color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896887/android-change-listview-font-and-color)