# How to set custom font for listview android?

Tags: android

I want to set custom listview in android:

[image: Here is the code]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. start by not linking your question to an image in imgr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom font in android ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576441/custom-font-in-android-listview)

Comment: Try the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576441/custom-font-in-android-listview) Hope this helps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896887/android-change-listview-font-and-color Hope this might help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom ListView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305899/custom-listview-android)

Answer (score 0):

You **can't apply font directly to listview** and you need to create **Custom Adapter** for listview and change it font.

for more details click below stack post it's already discussed.

[How to change color and font on ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361135/how-to-change-color-and-font-on-listview)