# Can I change ListVIew Text Color?

Tags: android, android-listview

Thanks all of you!! I am beginning of Android.I have a little problem.I use ListView, When I run this programe then my all List Item is White Color!!! How do this text color black or anthor please anyone help me!!

[image]

```
package com.example.shikkokoverflow_listview;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String[] country={"Bangladesh","usa","america","india","Florida"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, country);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), country[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}
```

Comment: could you please post code of your adapter?

Comment: You can use a Custom Layout having a textview and set color to the same.

Comment: Here is an [example][1] using CustomListAdapter


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7361323/395659

Comment: i post my code thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, do these steps

- Go to sdk folder  \sdk\platforms\android-\data\res\layout
- Copy simple_list_item_1 and paste it in your projects res\layout folder
- Now open \res\layout\simple_list_item_1
- Add color attribute there.
- then change your
  `adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, country);`

  to

  `adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1, country);`

Answer (score 2):

```
getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.rgb(36, 33, 32));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a customized layout. Define a layout file with your own `View`s where you can customize your font, font color, font size, images if you need... and then simply use it in your `ArrayAdapter` declaration.

```
myAdapt = new MyArrayArrayAdapter(this, R.id.your_layout, list);
```

Comment: yah i know this.. but i can not understand this problem, because why my problem list item..

Answer (score 1):

Make a new layout file in `res/layout`. In that make the root element, a `TextView` (which cannot have any child). Then set all the necessary attributes and in addition to that set `android:textColor="#000000"`. In your code, while making the `ArrayAdapter` write this:

```
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.new_layout, country);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Okay, upvoted, but TextViews cannot have childs ;)

Comment: That's what I said :)

Comment: Hm, okay sounded a bit like `don't add children to the TextView`...

Answer (score 0):

You will use instead of predefined Adapter into custom list adapter the process of custom adapter is...

You can get the custom adapter in class like this...

```
 ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, mListItems);//listitem is your custom layout.....
listView .setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Custom adapter class you just add this....in your project...

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sample> {

public ArrayList<Sample> mlist;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater; 
private LinearLayout layout;
private View view;
private View mLastView;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sample> mlist) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.mlist = mlist;     
    this.context = context;     
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Sample item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public Sample getItem(int position) {
    return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);//listitem will be a your cutom layout here i use two textview in the same item...
    layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutSample);;
    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    text1.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem1());
    text2.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem2());
    return view;
}

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should make another activity with a colored textview and relate your listview to it ..... with

```
list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.row_txt,item));
```

Comment: `Another activity` Do you mean a separate layout?

Comment: yes .... seperate layout ..... you can do everything you want on textview and then relate it to your listview .......

Comment: What's the point of copying **exactly** my **same** answer?