# Programmatically setText color for linearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-text-color

Is there a way to do `android:textColor` programmatically for linearLayout which contains bunch of textViews?

Comment: Iterate over the children of the `LinearLayout`, calling `setTextColor()` on all children that are `instanceof TextView`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361135/how-to-change-color-and-font-on-listview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have given id to your LinearLayout, this should work :

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    TextView textView;
    for (int i=0; i<linearLayout.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        View view = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof TextView){
            textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, It was useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
( (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content));
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
      if (view instanceof TextView){
         TextView text= (TextView) view;
         text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
```